# Override css to create a tree view

Tags: html, css, redmine

I try to create a collapsible tree view to a redmine project list page. I tried the plugin but it's not work. So my alternative is use the css plugin to override the `ul`, `li` display like [this](http://bernholdtech.blogspot.de/2013/04/very-simple-pure-css-collapsible-list.html). Check below html and the custom css I created which not work. I don't know what's wrong

```css
.projects li > input + * {
 display: none;
}
 
.projects li > input:checked + * {
 display: block;
}

.projects li > input {
 display: none;
}

.projects label {
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
    <h2>Projects</h2>

<div id="projects-index">
 <ul class='projects root'>
  <li class='root'><div class='root'><a class="project root parent " href="/redmine/projects/abc">Company projects</a></div>
   <ul class='projects '>
    <li class='child'><div class='child'><a class="project child parent " href="/redmine/projects/abc">A-1.abc</a></div>
     <ul class='projects '>
      <li class='child'>
       <div class='child'><a class="project child parent " href="/redmine/projects/a-research">A. research</a></div>
       <ul class='projects '>
        <li class='child'><div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/test-rds">1. rds</a></div>
        </li><li class='child'><div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/test-bgx">test-bgx</a></div>
        </li><li class='child'><div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/3d">3. 3d</a></div>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </li>
      <li class='child'>
       <div class='child'><a class="project child parent " href="/redmine/projects/b-shop">B. shop</a></div>
       <ul class='projects '>
        <li class='child'><div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/du">1. DU</a></div>
        </li><li class='child'><div class='child'><a class="project child leaf my-project" href="/redmine/projects/d2m">D2m</a></div>
        </li><li class='child'><div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/m2s">3. m2s</a></div>
        </li><li class='child'><div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/korean">4. korean</a></div>
        </li><li class='child'><div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/2msms">6. C2msms</a></div>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </li>
      <li class='child'>
       <div class='child'><a class="project child parent " href="/redmine/projects/c-others">C. Others</a></div>
       <ul class='projects '>
        <li class='child'><div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/summary">1. summary</a></div>
        </li><li class='child'><div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/group">2. group</a></div>
        </li><li class='child'><div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/yearly">3. yearly</a></div>
        </li><li class='child'><div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/prj">prj</a></div>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: There are no input tag in your html...

Comment: If you follow exactly the instruction in the link you mentioned, it will work. here is [a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lnefppc1/1/) just by copying and pasting the html and css inside the link.

Comment: in the blog, it uses input (checkbox) to allow for hiding and showing elements (perusing the "checked" attribute). If you don't want to use input as they have done, you need javascript to make it happen. CSS by itself does not have an "onclick" function. It has :hover, :visited, :active none of which will help if you want a click on to open the menu. However, if you want to hover to open, you can do so with CSS.

Comment: Hi, I have very limited right to change the html code, I can only insert a segment of javascript or css into it. Are there any viable solutions ?

Comment: This plugin may also help you: https://github.com/jbbarth/redmine_better_crossprojects. It replaces the default projects page in Redmine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final code which works for you. Check

```
$("li a.parent").on("click", function (e) {

    $(this).parent().parent().children('ul').toggle();
     e.preventDefault()
     e.stopPropagation();
});
$(function(){
$('li.child>ul.projects li.child').children('li>ul').hide();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

For collapsible tree view, you have to contain an element whose contain a previous status of a menu.For example, there I use a checkbox to handle a toggle event for child Items of the Menu list.Like this, you can design your code accordingly assign a toggle status in a checkbox.

> Demo HTML:

```
<ul class="tree">
 <li>
  <label for="checkbox1">Click to open list 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />
  <ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
  <label for="checkbox2">Click to open list 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" />
  <ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

> demo CSS:

```
.tree li > input[type=checkbox] + * {
 display: none;
}

.tree li > input[type=checkbox]:checked + * {
 display: block;
}

.tree li > input[type=checkbox] {
 display: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have very limited right to change the html code (in the question), I can only insert a segment of javascript or css into it. Are there any viable solutions ?

Comment: There I have a code for you which works with existing class only if you have jquery in your code. 
 `$(".child.parent").on("click",function(){
 var ul = $(this).parent().next("ul");
  if(ul.css("display") == 'none')
  {
   ul.show();
  }
  else
  {
   ul.hide();
  }
  
});`

Comment: Hi, can you please edit this fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/Lnefppc1/ I try to implement but it ain't work.

Comment: Hi, your code is not working with my html code. But I have this code is quite close to my goal, can you help? I just want to show to the 2nd level (A-1.ABC) the rest is toogle off onload. https://jsfiddle.net/hkL0xjvv/

Comment: actually, you not add an external link for jquery and also you can't contain a link on the Main menu from where you want to toggle.[https://jsfiddle.net/itsaddy/hkL0xjvv/1/

Comment: I don't get your idea. I can integrate this jsfiddle.net/hkL0xjvv to my site and it works. But it still shows anything so it's messy :( I want to show the first level child only, the rest are toogle off.

Comment: Thanks :D It's very close. Can you help me 2 things? First; can you hide all child of A-Research? Is this possible? Second, I want to click at the plus sign only to show/hide, now I click everywhere on the row and it still trigger show/hide.

Comment: This is not possible; pseudo-elements are not part of the DOM at all so you can't bind any events directly to them, you can only bind to their parent elements.

If you must have a click handler on the red region only, you have to make a child element, like a span, place it right after the opening <li> tag, apply styles to li span instead of li: before and bind to it. and for your first question take this https://jsfiddle.net/itsaddy/hkL0xjvv/3/

Comment: Hi, It's work quite well. Please paste your snipset to the reply section so I can mark it answered. Thank you, you are very kind and helpful. God bless you :D